# Can a Davidic King rule while his father is still alive?

Tags: malchut-royalty, king-david

Can a King of the House of David (i.e an inherited - not appointed - King), serve as king while his father is still alive?

I *think* King Shlomo might have been king during his father's lifetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly. It is explicit in the beginning of Melachim Aleph ([1:30](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.1.30?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)) that King David ordered for Solomon to reign in his lifetime, which answers your question.

> כִּ֡י כַּאֲשֶׁר֩ נִשְׁבַּ֨עְתִּי לָ֜ךְ בַּיהוָ֨ה אֱלֹהֵ֤י יִשְׂרָאֵל֙
>   לֵאמֹ֔ר כִּֽי־שְׁלֹמֹ֤ה בְנֵךְ֙ יִמְלֹ֣ךְ אַחֲרַ֔י וְה֛וּא יֵשֵׁ֥ב
>   עַל־כִּסְאִ֖י תַּחְתָּ֑י כִּ֛י כֵּ֥ן אֶעֱשֶׂ֖ה הַיּ֥וֹם הַזֶּֽה׃
>
> As I swore unto you by the Lord, the God of Israel, saying: Assuredly
>   Solomon your son shall reign after me, and he shall sit upon my throne
>   in my stead; verily so will I do this day.’

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your first two answers! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: I'd like to second @mbloch's welcome, and also make a suggestion. It would make this answer more valuable if you quote the text that makes it explicit inside the answer. You can copy (with attribution) text from sites such as sefaria.org.

Comment: In case it is not clear how to do it, I edited your answer with an example quote. Not sure if that is the one you would have used so feel free to edit again. Also sefaria (which I used) has an outdated translation so I typically update the translation where required

Comment: @mbloch If you are going to adjust the translation, you should say so explicitly so it doesn't look like someone's claiming something is Sefaria's translation when it isn't. (like say "translation adapted from Sefaria's" or something like that)

Comment: @DoubleAA you are right. Although I don't think I ever changed the meaning. It is rather modernizing thee -> you, Lord -> God, etc. but your point is fully taken and I will take care

Comment: Do we know what Shelomo's status was at the time? Could his wives perform Chalitza? Did he need to write a Torah?

Comment: Uziahu's son reigned during his lifetime, also. In both cases the reigning king was unfit to rule, and so their sons took over.